# hasOneThrough condition on intermediate model

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I currently have three tables in my database:

Student:
id,
guardian_relation_id,

StudentGuardian:
id,
student_id,
guardian_id,
guardian_type,

Guardian:
id,
name,
I have a relationship function in my Student model:

```
public function guardian(){
    return $this->hasOneThrough(Guardian::class,StudentGuardian::class,'student_id','id','id','guardian_id');
}
```

This relationship function is functioning as expected. However, I now want to retrieve data where guardian_relation_id matches with guardian_type. How can I achieve this using Laravel Eloquent?

Comment: what value will be there in the `guardian_relation_id`, `guradian_type`?

Comment: @MiteshRathod guardian types/guardian_relation_id 1 , 2 & 3